# Python sqlite3, refer to a variable in execute statement

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite3.connect.cursor.execute in Python to manipulate database, but not sure how to correctly construct the SELECT statement so that the tbname in the code below can be properly read in as a variable.

I tried to leave tbname outside the ending quotation mark, hoping that in this way Python knows tbname is a variable. However the code doesn't work. Any idea?

```
def print_col(dbname, tbname):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = \'table\' AND tbl_name = '+ tbname)
    print c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: What error do you get? How do you call print_col?

Comment: Hi, I got below error:

c.execute('SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = \'table\' AND tbl_name = ' + tbname)  OperationalError: no such column: details

Comment: And I call the print_col function by asking for user input:  
dbname2 = raw_input('Please enter a database name (grades.db/program.db): ')
tbname2 = raw_input('Please enter a table name (courses/details): ')
print_col(dbname2, tbname2)

Answer (score 0):

This is what parameters are for:

```
c.execute("SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND tbl_name = ?", (tbname,))
```